# How do I send arguments into loadTexture's callback function?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, callback, three.js

My code:

```
var textureMap = {};
var map = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3};
for ( var key in map) {
   var url = "images/" + key+ ".png";
   var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(url, {}, function() {
        textureMap[key] = texture;
        console.log(key);    // becomes c all times
   });

}
```

How am I able to send in the key as an argument into the callback function? So that I fill the textureMap with 3 textures, and not overwrite it at same key. Probably a very basic javascript question, I'd appreciate a quick answer!

Thanks

**SOLVED** it pretty quick in this way:

```
var textureMap = {};
var map = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3};
for ( var key in map) {
   var url = "images/" + key+ ".png";
   var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(url, {}, (function(key) {
        textureMap[key] = texture;
        console.log(key);    // outputs, a,b,c
   })(key));

}
```

Comment: The keys have no values; the above is invalid JavaScript syntax

Comment: Aye, typed the wrong map example, fixed now.